# canvas text and image is fuzzy and blurry

Tags: php, jquery, canvas, charts, canvasjs

I am implementing graphs in materializecss using canvasJS but the text and image is fuzzy and blurry Here is the code which I have taken from the official website of canvasjs

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
    title:{
        text: "Top Oil Reserves"
    },
    axisY: {
        title: "Reserves(MMbbl)"
    },
    data: [{        
        type: "column",  
        showInLegend: true, 
        legendMarkerColor: "grey",
        legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
        dataPoints: [      
            { y: 300878, label: "Venezuela" },
            { y: 266455,  label: "Saudi" },
            { y: 169709,  label: "Canada" },
            { y: 158400,  label: "Iran" },
            { y: 142503,  label: "Iraq" },
            { y: 101500, label: "Kuwait" },
            { y: 97800,  label: "UAE" },
            { y: 80000,  label: "Russia" }
        ]
    }]
});
chart.render();
```

```html
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `y axis` text is pixelated. You can use `titleFontFamily` on `axisY` to use a font that renders more to your liking. In the snippet below I used `verdana`.

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
        animationEnabled: true,
        theme: "light2", // "light1", "light2", "dark1", "dark2"
        title:{
            text: "Top Oil Reserves"
        },
        axisY: {
            title: "Reserves(MMbbl)",
            titleFontFamily: "verdana"
        },
       
        data: [{        
            type: "column",  
            showInLegend: true, 
            legendMarkerColor: "grey",
            legendText: "MMbbl = one million barrels",
            dataPoints: [      
                { y: 300878, label: "Venezuela" },
                { y: 266455,  label: "Saudi" },
                { y: 169709,  label: "Canada" },
                { y: 158400,  label: "Iran" },
                { y: 142503,  label: "Iraq" },
                { y: 101500, label: "Kuwait" },
                { y: 97800,  label: "UAE" },
                { y: 80000,  label: "Russia" }
            ]
        }]
    });
    chart.render();
```

```html
    <body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 300px; width: 100%;"></div>
    <script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```